Determining if this interval is true or false. $\int_{-2}^2\left(x^5-9x^{11} + \frac{\sin(x)}{(1+x^4)^2}\right)dx = 0$?
How would one determine whether this expression is true or false?
$$\int_{-2}^2\left(x^5-9x^{11} + \frac{\sin(x)}{(1+x^4)^2}\right)dx = 0$$
I've been able to get to where the first part of the integral$(x^5-9x^{11})=0$, but the second part I can't figure out.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Try to show it is an odd function

I think that, since the integrand is an odd function over a symmetric interval, that this expression would be true (= 0).

@Blossompot you're correct :) what are you confused about?

@WasuChanyasubkit I just wasn't sure if I was correct lol!

The function you want to integrate is odd which implies that its integral over a symmetric interval is equal to 0.

It does not "mean". It "implies". Isn't it ?

This could maybe be a comment
